Looking for an old anime from 90s or early 2000's
I remember watching it a few decades ago, there was a pregnant girl who was being chased by bad guys and the baby that she was carrying gave her psychic powers (telekinetic powers) while pregnant. She was able to control her baby's power to defend herself. When her baby was born, she no longer had those powers, it was all the child's.

I know there was a character like this in Toaru Majutsu no Index (Freyja), but I don't think she ever made the transition from light novel to anime.  There's also the character Videl from Dragonball Super, a human who channels her unborn half-Saiyin child's power.

Ah thanks, but it wasn't this one. I remember watching it on a site called veoh back in the day. I think the year is between 2001 and 2004
